# Passing Objekt to JqueryPlugin and iterates through them

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I wrote a Jquery Calendar Plugin.
Now I want to learn to Pass Parameter to it, to change the View of the calendar.

```
$.kalender({element: "#Clock", property: "display", value: "none"},{element:"#MainDiv", property:"width" ,value:"500px"});
```

these are my objects that im passing to my Plugin.

```
;(function (namespace, $) {
$.extend({
    kalender: function (options) {

        //Use Parameter   

        if (options !== undefined) {
            $.each(options, function () {                
                $(options.element).css(options.property, options.value);
            });  
        }
```

Jquery always just takes the first object.(So the Plugin doesn't display the clock). 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never access the iteratee object in your `$.each` function. The code should be:

```
 $.each(options, function (index, option) {                
        $(option.element).css(option.property, option.value);
    });
```

And when you call it should be:

```
$.kalender([{element: "#Clock", property: "display", value: "none"},{element:"#MainDiv", property:"width" ,value:"500px"}]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, if i console.log(option.element) or the others i get undefined.. If i consoloe.log(option) i get Elemetn, property and Value back...

Comment: Have you added the array? i.e .`$.kalender([...`

Comment: my bad... i had a typo. Check the answer again.